# Differnece between build configuration in ios project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, build-settings

We have got legacy code base from an organization to maintain. Its huge project developed using objective C and Cocoa touch. It has 10-12 build configurations, like staging, dev, prod etc.. Other than this I see many other build configurations, which are dont seems to be in use. I just want to keep debug, release and appstore because only the base url differs. My questions are -

1)How do I clean up all these build configurations? 
2)How do I compare existing build configurations and delete duplicate one?

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

By Build Configuration, you mean "Targets"?
Generally we create different targets for different purposes. Like we would want the app to talk to dev server when the dev target is used and so on.
You might want to keep different targets in your app.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. I meant the schemas that we create to build the target. We can create these schemas as configs. I have multiple schemas to build one target. Before deleting that schema, I want to know why it was created? I do have Staging, PreProd and AppStore schemas, other than the base url difference, i want to know was there any other difference in achemas.